# Get Accuracy of myLocationOverlay

Tags: android, mylocationoverlay

Is there a way to get the accuracy of the fix from MyLocationOverlay? It obviously knows how accurate it is since it draws the circle of the area of how accurate it is. Is there away to get this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code from my location listener in one of my apps...

```
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLatitudeE6 = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        currentLongitudeE6 = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        currentAccuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        hasCurrentPosition = true;
        gpsMessage = "GPS Tracking";
        updateMap();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement Location Listener by locationManager.requestLocationUpdates method, check following link:

http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/